# Error while declaring a new variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create a new variable (average of AGE) that I would like to get from another table named:`source_table`.
I wrote the following lines but got an error:

```
DECLARE @mean_AGE decimal; 
set @mean_AGE = select AVG( AGE ) from source_table;
```

Error details:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 33
>       Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.

How can I solve this issue?

An update:
I used this code based on the answers below but still an error.

```
 DECLARE @mean_AGE decimal; 
 select @mean_AGE = AVG(AGE) from source_table;

 --DELETE temp_table
SELECT TOP 1000 
       [AGE]=iif(AGE='NA',@mean_AGE,AGE)
      INTO temp_table
  FROM [source_table]

But got this error:
Must declare the scalar variable "@mean_AGE".
```

Comment: Use braces around the query; `SET @var = ( SELECT value FROM blah )` or use the query to assign a variable directly; `SELECT @var = value FROM blah`

Answer (score 0):

Change the query to:

```
select @mean_AGE = AVG(AGE) from source_table;
```

---

**Updates**

Remove those semi-colons

```
DECLARE @mean_AGE decimal
select @mean_AGE = AVG(AGE) from source_table
```

`;` denotes end of batch script so a statement after that is effectively new batch script.

Secondly,

This one will not work because the data type in iif true and false condition must match.

```
SELECT TOP 1000 
   [AGE]=iif(AGE='NA',@mean_AGE,AGE)
  INTO temp_table
FROM [source_table]
```

Change to:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 
   [AGE]=iif(AGE=0,@mean_AGE,AGE)
  INTO temp_table
FROM [source_table]
```

Comment: Hello Sunil, please see my update. I still get an error.

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect new updates to the question.

Comment: Yes remove those semi-colons

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead, use a select. `set @mean_AGE = (select AVG( AGE ) from source_table)`

Comment: read this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/select-local-variable-transact-sql

Comment: The change you made that matters is adding the braces, `SET @mean_AGE` or `SELECT @mean_AGE` would ***both*** work in your example, because you have `= ( <query> )` where the OP just has `= <query>`